# Understand the meaning of this piece of code?

Tags: python-3.x

What does this code mean?

```
class Singleton(object):
    _instances = {}

    def __new__(class_, *args, **kwargs):
        if class_ not in class_._instances:
            class_._instances[class_] = super(Singleton, class_).__new__(class_, *args, **kwargs)  # noqa E501
        return class_._instances[class_]
```

Comment: What specifically don't you understand?

Comment: all of it, can you elaborate on it? Thank you Amy.

Comment: @Amy why the negative, I'm new to OOP?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271468/explain-x-to-me-questions-how-to-react

Comment: You asked why I downvoted, and I answered.  You'll find your answer if you read past the title of the linked post.  Your question is too broad.

Answer (score 1):

This is a parent class for creating Singleton classes.  The Singleton pattern means that there is only one instance of a class.  (For example, `None` is the only instance of the `NoneType` class).

This works by creating a map of classes to instances, `_instances`.  It has overridden the default `__new__` method so that whenever someone tries to create a new instance, it either uses the existing instance from the map or stores the new instance in the map.